# Compiz Freezes Computer using Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, compiz

I have an Ubuntu 9.04 PC with an nVidia graphics system running at 1920x1080 outputting through an HDMI port. This all works fine until I enable the visual effects from the System > Preferences > Appearance... dialog. Then, the screen update freezes and the screen updates, when they happen, tend to contain bits of other windows / corruption. The system is still running, albeit very sluggishly, so I can switch the effect off. I'm using the restricted nVidia drivers (there may be a newer driver, but I've tried a few versions and they all exhibit the same problem).

Any ideas what's going on and how to fix it?

Cheers.

EDIT

From what I remember (the PC is at home, I'm writing this at the office), it's [using this  motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Products/Motherboard/Products_Overview.aspx?ProductID=2946) which has an nVidia GeForce 9400 on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have managed to fix this.
First of all, I uninstalled the video driver using:

```
sudo sh NVIDIA.... --uninstall
```

where "NVIDIA...." is the video driver file. I'm writing this from memory so the argument might be wrong, it is in the readme how to do it. Then, after reading a few forums about this issue, I unsintalled all the nvidia components using:

```
sudo apt-get remove "nvidia*"
```

Then I installed the new driver, restarted, and so far it appears to be working OK.

Also, to help install the driver, I modified run level 5 to disable GDM and used the 'telinit' command to change the run level.

Skizz

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a different video driver if you can, because it sounds like the current one your using is not working correctly. Which nvidia card does that computer use? I assume if your computer has a hdmi port, you probaly at least have a halfway decent video chipset, just need to find working drivers. I had a laptop once that would just crash/freeze if I attempted to turn on visual effects and things like berl. I think it was just too old though and no driver update could help it.